# Good practice for Request and Request.Form in asp.net webpages 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, forms, razor, request

I'm reading some tutorials about asp.net webpages 2 and I found something confusing

In this page: http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/working-with-pages/validating-user-input-in-aspnet-web-pages-sites the following code:

```
<form method="post">
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
    <div>
        <label for="coursename">Course name: </label>
        <input type="text" name="coursename" value="@Request["coursename"]" />
        @Html.ValidationMessage("coursename")
   </div>
...
```

Is it "correct" to use in this case just Request["fieldname"] instead of Request.Form["fieldname"]? I understand(please correct if wrong) that request will also check for fields in the querystring while request.form will only check within the form's fields.

Might this create any kind of errors/security problems... is a good or bad use of request...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you request a value with `@Request[key]`, then the framework search for a value in the following steps (if nothing was found, it goes to the next step):

1. `Request.QueryString[key]`
2. `Request.Form[key]`
3. `Request.Cookies[key]`
4. `Request.ServerVariables[key]`

But I think it's a better option to directly get your value from the collection you want it from. It's better for the security of our app and also better for the maintenance.

**Update**: I've written a blog post about this [on my blog](http://ctor.io/using-httprequest-item-property/).

Answer (score 2):

It is correct to use either way, either Request.Form or simply Request to pull the value from the QueryString. The only issue you might encounter is if you have a querystring and form field with the same name. In both cases though you should already be testing and validating the data on the server to handle any errors. A user could edit the Request.Form object before it goes to the server almost as easy as if they could edit the querystring. At a minimum you should have:

```
<input type="text" name="coursename" value="@Server.UrlEncode(Request["coursename"])" />
```

ASP.Net MVC uses the Request method by default when mapping values to the parameters of the action being run in a controller. So it seems to be good enough for Microsoft to use Request["coursename"].